# Wildcard filter for text from 2 different text files in java

Tags: java, netbeans

I have 2 text files. myfile.txt and Person.txt. myfile.txt contains a short passage and Person.txt have list of people names. For now i'm doing this program with netbeans. The GUI have 2 textarea and a button. When i click on that button, contents of myfile.txt will be shown in 1st textarea and 2nd textarea should show Person if any name from Person.txt is found in myfile.txt. So far i can show the myfile.txt in 1 textarea but could not do the comparison.
This is my code for now:
     private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        int a = 0;

```
    try{
        FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("myfile.txt");
        // use DataInputStream to read binary NOT text
        // DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(fstream));
        String line="";

        FileInputStream fstreamCP = new FileInputStream("Person.txt");
        // use DataInputStream to read binary NOT text
        // DataInputStream inCP = new DataInputStream(fstreamCP);
        BufferedReader brCP = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(fstreamCP));
        String lineCP = brCP.readLine();

        while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
            System.out.println();
            jTextArea1.append(line);

            if (jTextArea1.getText()==(lineCP)){
                jTextArea2.append("Person");
            }
        }

        in.close();
        }catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println("Error while reading file:" + e.getMessage());
        }

}
```

The above code have no error. Can read and send content of myfile.txt to 1st textarea but cannot identify the same words that exist in myfile.txt and Person.txt. I guess if i use wildcard text filter so i will be able to do this? Any idea or sample code highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Its not working. Because the mytext.txt have a short passage and must compare with Person.txt.
For example:

mytext.txt contains-

Hi my name is John.

Person.txt contains-

Oliver
Harry
Bane
John
Melissa

Answer (score 0):

Don't compare Strings with `==`:

```
jTextArea1.getText()==(lineCP)
```

This checks to see if the two String variables refer to the exact same String object, and this is not what you are interested in.

Instead use the `.equals(...)` or `.equalsIgnoreCase(...)`  methods. These methods check to see if two Strings have the same chars in the same order, either case sensitive (the first method) or insensitive, and this is what you want to check.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use equals() for strings, you can not compare them with =

```
if (jTextArea1.getText().equals(lineCP)){
    jTextArea2.append("Person");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`==` is known as `relational operators in Java`. It will Checks if the values of two operands are equal or not, if yes then condition becomes true.

Use `equals()` or `equalsIgnoreCase()` for your case....

```
if (lineCP.equals(jTextArea1.getText())){
     jTextArea2.append("Person");
}

or

if (lineCP.equalsIgnoreCase(jTextArea1.getText())){
     jTextArea2.append("Person");
}
```